# B2B tax rules 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, tax-class

I have a shop in Belgium and my company in The Netherlands, so when a B2B customer place a order and have a correct Tax number the tax have to be 0% 
can somebody tell me how I need to setup the tax in the backend so the Tax have to be 0% when the tax number is controlled by Magento or a exstension system ?

Comment: we use the EuVat extension https://support.pillwax.com/open-source/doku.php?id=magento:euvat works great